# I have an Error with my books example code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

I have this code from books tutorial:

```
 void drawShapes (id shapes[], int count)
 {
int i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
id shape = shapes[i];
[shape draw];
 }

}
```

And Xcode reports me Error: 
"Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Must explicitly describe intended ownership of an object array parameter".

What's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming from your name that you can read Russian, [here is one possible answer to the same question](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=156247).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an auto-releasing array, change your function declaration to:

```
void drawShapes (id __autoreleasing shapes[], int count)
```

and that should take care of your error!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is brought by Automatic Reference Counting.
ARC is brought by Apple after iOS5.0. In default iOS project, ARC is selected.
When using ARC, you should mention that the Array must using NSArray, or you must tell the complier the array not an ARC object.

There are two methods to solve the problem. Two methods both work.

1.First Method
like a previous posted answer:

```
void drawShapes (id __autoreleasing shapes[], int count)
```

tell the complier don't use ARC on this C type Array shapes[].

Or
2.Second Method, stop using ARC to your project

If this project is iOS project, you can recreate a iOS project, then deselect the "Auto Reference Counting" in the dialog.

If this project is Mac OS Project(or you don't want to create a new iOS project), go to the project setting page, then select "Building Settings" tag, search "Automatic Reference Counting", then set the relative value to "NO".

Answer (score -2):

Instead of [shape draw]; you should actually put some code that draws the shape.
Right now the compiler thinks that this [shape draw] is an array operator []. But since you didn't provide the name of the array, you got an error.

Comment: That's Objective-C message send syntax. Assuming that `shape` is an object (and it is -- `id` is the generic object type), it's valid. This also has no relation to the posted error message.