# What does "Must explicitly describe intended ownership of an object array parameter" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is something wrong with the first line of the following function definition:

```
void draw(id shapes[], int count)
{   
    for(int i = 0;i < count;i++) {
        id shape = shapes[i];
        [shape draw];
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with the error "Must explicitly describe intended ownership of an object array parameter".

What is the exact cause of the error? How can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to include the language in the question title; the tags contain that information. Also, please don't use abbreviations like "sth"; stick to grammatically correct English. If you're giving an error message, please state so explicitly. Error messages make it easy to find existing questions. Always search before posting to make sure you're not asking a duplicate.

Comment: Dup of [I have an Error with my books example code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796910/i-have-an-error-with-my-books-example-code)

Comment: @outis I think if you put language in title it helps people who are googling the same problem.

Comment: @bakalolo: If it works within the question, maybe, but SE sites already add the primary tag to the title. Dropping it in, however, produces a word soup that doesn't describe the question well. See the site guidelines on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7):

You are passing an array of pointers in an [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) environment. You need to specify one of the following:

- __strong
- __weak
- __unsafe_unretained
- __autoreleasing

I think in your case `__unsafe_unretained` should work, assuming that you do not do anything to the shapes that you pass to `draw()` concurrently.

```
void draw(__unsafe_unretained id shapes[], int count)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < count;i++) {
        id shape = shapes[i];
        [shape draw];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! is ARC means Garbage Collector ？

Comment: @itenyh No, it's Automated Reference Counting. It is very, very different from garbage collector. I put a link into the answer pointing to Apple's document explaining the concept of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and reading this I solved my problem, I tried with the property __unsafe_unretained but didn't work for me, the compiler show me, you are trying to pass a Strong var into unsafe_unretained. So with __strong work fine in the book sample.

```
void draw(__strong id shapes[], int count)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < count;i++) {
        id shape = shapes[i];
        [shape draw];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is to disable the ARC in Xcode.

Select your project or target and then go to **Build Settings** and under the section **Apple LLVM compiler 8.1 - Language** you will see the option **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting**. Set it to **NO**.